# how to make a bot that gives role when we join a particular voice channel and removes when left

Tags: python, discord.py

I am learning how to use discord.py and I want to make bot feature that give role when we join particular voice channel and removes the same role when user leaves the channel

```py
@client.event
async def on_voice_state_update():
```

Comment: hi, is there a command to grant status

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`on_voice_state_update` gives you `after` and `before` arguments, here's how to check when a member joined and left a voice channel

```py
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    if before.channel is None and after.channel is not None:
        # member joined a voice channel, add the roles here
    elif before.channel is not None and after.channel is None:
        # member left a voice channel, remove the roles here
```

To add roles, first you need to get a `discord.Role` object, then you can do `member.add_roles(role)`

```py
role = member.guild.get_role(role_id)

await member.add_roles(role)
```

To remove a role is the same, but `.remove_roles`

```py
await member.remove_roles(role)
```

EDIT:

```py
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    channel = before.channel or after.channel

    if channel.id == some_id:
        if before.channel is None and after.channel is not None:
            # member joined a voice channel, add the roles here
        elif before.channel is not None and after.channel  is None:
            # member left a voice channel, remove the roles here
```

Reference:

- [`on_voice_state_update`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_voice_state#discord.on_voice_state_update)
- [`Guild.get_role`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=get_role#discord.Guild.get_role)
- [`Member.add_roles`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=add_roles#discord.Member.add_roles)
- [`Member.remove_roles`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=remove_role#discord.Member.remove_roles)

Comment: and how to make it give and remove role when join and left in particular voice channel ?

Comment: Check for the channels name/id, I edited my answer

Comment: @client.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
  channel = before or after

  if channel.id == 792778963302744094:
    if before.voice is None and after.voice is not None:
      role = member.guild.get_role(791601378593734667)
      await member.add_roles(role)
    elif before.voice is not None and after.voice is None:
      role = member.guild.get_role(791601378593734667)
      await member.remove_roles(role)

like this ??? it is giving me error