# how to make a discord.py bot that send embedded message in particular channel when user join a particular voice channel

Tags: discord.py

I am learning discord.py and I want to make bot that sends embedded message like.(@user has joined!) joined  in particular text channel only eg.(#music-cnsole) when users join particular voice channel eg.(music.vc)

- **like this**
  [image]

***when user joins***

- **also**
  [image]

***when user leaves***

```
@client.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to make a bot that gives role when we join a particular voice channel and removes when left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65446794/how-to-make-a-bot-that-gives-role-when-we-join-a-particular-voice-channel-and-re)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
channelId = 1234567891011 # Your text channel id here
voiceChannelId = 1234567891011 # Your voice channel id here

@bot.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    if ((before.channel != None and before.channel.id == voiceChannelId) or (after.channel != None and after.channel.id == voiceChannelId)): # if connected/disconected to voiceChannelId channel
        channel = bot.get_channel(channelId) # gets channel object
        if (before.channel == None and after.channel != None): # if user connect
            channel.send(f"{member.mention} connected to voice {after.channel.name}") # send message to channel
        elif (before.channel != None and after.channel == None): # if user disconnect
            channel.send(f"{member.mention} disconnect from voice {before.channel.name}") # send message to channel
```

[`on_voice_state_update` event in docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_voice_state_update#discord.on_voice_state_update)

Pardon for many edits.